# How to best track opportunities by their products' "active" dates for a report?

Tags: formula, reporting, opportunity, date, opportunity-lineitem

Simply stated, my goal is to write an accrual report that lists all closed/won opportunities by each month (with each month including in an opportunity only if any of its products are active during that month). I do have a field for the number of days an opportunity runs (product end date - start date) as well as the average price per day (total opp price / # of days), but I can't figure out how to accomodate the opportunities which run for mulitple months. Hopefully this explanation makes sense. So:

1. How do I create a field that indicates the sum of the total months/dates that an opportunity and its products cover? I figured I'd use that field to sort active opps in the report, but should I be heading in a different direction?
2. Once I know the total dates/months, how do I split an opportunity within a report to reflect the $ spent per each month? For example, let's say there's an opportunity with a total price $1500 has a product that runs 5 days in January and 10 in February. How do I correctly note that the opp is active in January/February and show that the opp is credited $500 for January and $1000 for February?

Comment: i think you have a schema issue, the unit of reporting sounds like it has to be a object called `ActiveProductPeriod` which represents a sku/YYYYMM/amount and has a lookup to the OpportunityLineItem (or possibly to the Opportunity)

Comment: Ah okay. So if I have the "start date', "end date" and "# of days" for the opplineitem, what's the best method/formula to calculate the months represented in between those dates?